# How can I make an image masthead similar to a photo viewer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, template

I have been seeing this template or effect on instagram storie.

So I wanted to ask how can to make them?

Or if I can download the template and add pictures in them with Photoshop.

It looks like MacOs photo viewer. I tried googling it but couldn’t fine anything unfortunately.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply a bar with three circles and centered text.

You can create this is just about any software.

Illustrator....

[image]

Photoshop....

[image]

Then you simply place it at the top of your photo and save.

---

If you are unfamiliar with how to draw boxes and circles in any application, you may do better to check the help files for the application you prefer to use. Almost all applications will have basic help instructions on using the basic tools they contain.